# Enable/Disable dynamic eventlistener on a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a stateless React component `<Input>` that I need to add a **keyPress** event , when the component is **type=number**

Here is my code so far:

```js
function Input({
  input: {
    name,
    onBlur,
    onChange,
    ...attributes
  },
  label,
  onBeforeBlur,
  onBeforeChange,
  placeholder,
  type,
  autoCapitalize,
  displayValid,
  disabled = false,
}) {
  // I added the event listener function
  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    if (!(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="field--wrapper">
      <div className="field">
        <div className={classNames}>
          <input
            {...attributes}
            autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
            className="input__input"
            disabled={disabled}
            id={id || name}
            name={name}
            onBlur={onBeforeBlur ? onBeforeBlur(onBlur) : onBlur}
            onChange={onBeforeChange ? onBeforeChange(onChange) : onChange}
            type={type || "text"}
            // This is the event listener, when not number I assign false!! Is this correct?
            onKeyPress={type === "number" ? handleKeyPress : false}
          />
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But there are some components that `input type=text` and if so, I don't want to assign the `keypress` event listener, so I check the type:

```js
onKeyPress={type === 'number' ? handleKeyPress : false}
```

It seems to work, but is it an accepted method? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think since you are checking for the correct character codes in `handleKeyPress`, checking if the type is a number is redundant. In the function you can simply check the char codes, as you are doing, and the perform some code if the check passes.

Comment: Yes it works, you can write even with a better syntax like this : `onKeyPress={ type === 'number' && handleKeyPress }`.

Comment: yes, i like it better.